# Run code before url mapping on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'd like to check the datastore first, to see if there is any data, and if not, then redirect to another page (most likely `/admin`). However, I don't want to rewrite the url mapping framework that is already there.

Is there some way to set a handler that will process all requests before they are mapped?

I'm using google app engine with Python 2.7 and webapp2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [override dispatch()](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch) with a custom class.  In the example shown in the link, the new class name is `MyHandler`.  This means that all of your request classes need to be derived from `MyHandler` instead of `webapp2.RequestHandler`.  Since this is how you would implement [Sessions](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html?highlight=sessions), you can put your code in `dispatch()` before it calls `webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)`.  In other words, you probably want to replace `webapp2.RequestHandler` anyway.

Comment: Perfect. That also means certain handlers (like for admin pages) don't have pass through the same checks. Seems to be working well.